# if $M$ is compact, then every continuous bijection $F:M\to N$ is an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, continuity

My book proves that:

if $M$ is compact, then every continuous bijection $f:M\to N$ is an homeomorphism

by the following:

Being $f$ closed, your inverse $g:N\to M$ is a function such that $F\subset M$ closed $\implies g^{-1}(F) = f(F) \subset N$ is closed. Then, $g$ is continuous.

Well, I know that $f$ is closed because $M$ is compact, but why does $g^{-1}$ being closed proves that $g$ is closed? As far as I know, I should prove that $g=f^{-1}$ is closed, not $g^{-1}$.

Comment: You have to prove that $g=f^{-1}$ is *continuous* $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is closed.

Comment: Since $f$ is already a continuous bijection, by definition it is a homeomorphism if its inverse $g$ is continuous. (A homeomorphism is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse.) So the main goal is to prove $g$ is continuous. Now $g$ is continuous if it pulls closed sets back to closed sets, i.e. if $F\subset M$ is closed then $g^{-1}(M)$ needs to be closed. But $g^{-1}(M) = f(M)$. Thus $g$ is continuous if and only if $f$ is a closed map.

Comment: If you feel you already understand why $f$ is a closed map (i.e. $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets), then your main work is to understand why this is equivalent to $g$ being continuous (which is what I was just trying to explain, I don't know how clearly ;). But in my opinion the juiciest part of the question is understanding why $M$ being compact (and $M,N$ being metric spaces) imply that $f$ is a closed map. (Nigel's answer is mostly about this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be two metric spaces, with $X$ compact, and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous bijection.

Definition: The function $f$ is continuous if for every set $O \subset Y$ which is open in $Y$, $f^{-1}(O)$ is open in $X$.

Lemma: The function $f$ is continuous if and only if for every set $C \subset Y$ which is closed in $Y$, $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$.

Lemma: $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}=f$

Since it is already given that $f$ is continuous and bijective, we only have to proof that $f^{-1}:Y \to X$ is continuous. By the first lemma it is enough to prove that, for every closed $C \subset X$, $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $Y$. By the second lemma, we have that $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{-1}(C)=f(C)$. Hence we should prove that $f(C)$ is closed. This follows from the fact that $X$ is compact, so $C$ is also compact (closed subset of a compact space). It then follows that $f(C)$ is compact and hence closed.

This proves that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: +1 The proof uses the fact that in a metric space ($Y$), compact sets are closed, but nothing else about metric spaces. It follows that $f$ is a homeomorphism without even assuming $X$ is metric. In fact, as compact sets are closed in any Hausdorff space, it is enough to assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff.